# Is there a proof of the uniqueness of the solutions of Maxwell equations with non-fixed charges?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, determinism

I know that if $\rho(t,\vec x)$, $\vec J(t,\vec x)$, $\vec E(0,\vec x)$ and $\vec B(0,\vec x)$ are given beforehand, with $\nabla \cdot \vec E(0,\vec x) = 4\pi\rho(0,\vec x)$ and $\nabla \cdot \vec B(0,\vec x) = 0$, and $\rho(t,\vec x)$, $\vec J(t,\vec x)$ satisfying the continuity equations, then it generates a unique solution $\vec E(t,\vec x)$ and $\vec B(t,\vec x)$ to maxwell equations for all times. I have proven that on my electromagnetism ll undergrad course. But now I have the question of what happens when the currents are not fixed. To sleep in peace, I need a theorem that says something like:

Given $\rho(t,\vec x)$, $\vec J(t,\vec x)$ for $t<0$ (satisfying the continuity equations for those times), and $\vec E(0,\vec x)$ and $\vec B(0,\vec x)$, with $\nabla \cdot \vec E(0,\vec x) = 4\pi\rho(0,\vec x)$ and $\nabla \cdot \vec B(0,\vec x) = 0$, then it generates a unique solution $\vec E(t,\vec x)$, $\vec B(t,\vec x)$, $\rho(t,\vec x)$ and  $\vec J(t,\vec x)$ to maxwell equations for $t>0$.

Did somebody prove that? Is it true? Is it provable?

I am thinking on a simple situation in which I have two point like particles, with positive charge $q$, and a distance $L$ between them. They are fixed in space from $t = - \infty$, so for those times there are no radiation fields. At time $t = 0$, I kick both giving them instantaneously different velocities, and are no longer fixed in space. They are going to repel, move, create a magnetic field, accelerate, radiate some fields, accelerate the other with that fields, etc. The trayectories of these particles should be determined. I mean, the world is deterministic, and to be that way, there should be a theorem like the one I am asking.

Note: I am completely in the framework of classic electromagnetism, but fully relativistic (don't want any approximation), so I would like to solve the problem with no quantum mechanics appearing.

Comment: What do you mean by charges not being fixed? If you want to allow charges to evolve freely under the influence of the fields, you will need to provide equations that govern their dynamics. Charge and current density could be due to charged particle, or due to particle with electric/magnetic dipole moment etc. Also, Jackson, in Chap 16, I think has a discussion on difficulties of having charges evolve under the fields they generate. My memory from it is that situation there is not yet clear, i.e. equations give diverging solutions

Comment: Perhaps it is better to start proving this for one charged particle. Then for one charged particle+dipole moment, then for particle with arbitrary multipole moment, then several particles

Comment: @Cryo The situation in Jackson 16 describes why mass renormalization of point particles is necessary classically. This problem does not appear when dealing with non-singular charge/current distributions.

Comment: @RichardMyers, thanks, I am not an expert in this, so it is good to learn. However, if one has to consider distributions of charge and current density, this will lead to even more complex dynamics of motion. Also one must remember that current density could be due to neutral particles with some higher multipole moment (e.g. magnetization density etc)

Comment: @Cryo Life is complicated at times. That is not an argument against the existence of life. Furthermore, I will note that generally multipole moments should be viewed as an expansion of the charge density, so the full charge density already contains all such information. The formalism of classical mechanics provides an answer to this question without the need to consider specific realizations or approximations of various charge distributions.

Comment: @RichardMyers, I was not arguing, simply pointing out what should not be forgotten. Not sure about you comment on multipole expansion. Would you consider magnetization expressible as a charge density?

Comment: @Cryo No, magnetization is the result of a material property. This is distinct as it's an additional thing we add to our model of E&M. The multipole expansion is no different than expanding a solution to the heat equation into Fourier modes. You can attach whatever meaning to it you like to the terms in the expansion, but at the end of the day the solution is some function, regardless of what techniques or expansions are used to represent it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a missing ingredient to your question which is: given the initial conditions (fields, currents, and densities at $t=0$), what determines the evolution of the current and density? The continuity equation relates the current and density, but is not itself sufficient to determine the evolution completely.

Typically we take the the Lorentz force to be this missing ingredient (though material properties like conductivity can complicate matters). With this in mind, the equations of motion aren't just Maxwell's equation, but Maxwell's equations plus the Lorentz force equation. In general this makes problems extremely difficult and so is left as a numerical problem by and large (there's also an issue with point charges behaving exceptionally poorly).

Once we have all this in mind, however, there's a simple way to see that the dynamics will be uniquely determined assuming a solution exists at all (though it may not satisfy some people's desire for rigor). Notice that in Maxwell's equations and the Lorentz force law, the time derivatives of all quantities can be isolated, meaning we can write things in a form $\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}=(\cdots),\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}=(\cdots),\ldots$. The right-hand-side of each of these equations will involve the fields and their spatial derivatives, but that won't be a problem.

Imagine now we want to solve this system numerically. Since we start knowing the values of the fields at $t=0$, we can compute all necessary spatial derivatives on the RHS of our equations and write the time derivatives as a finite difference between the field value (at each spatial point) at $t=0$ and $t=0+\Delta t$. From the form of our equations (the time derivatives being isolated) we can clearly solve for the values of the fields at the time $t=\Delta t$.

Now, this is a very loose argument based on numerical thinking, but you could imagine arguing for the existence of a temporal power series by the same means, from which it follows that a solution will exist (there are various assumptions about analyticity that go into this, but more rigor can always be added to any argument and I just want to convey the idea). The only worry we might have is that the constraints are not preserved by the time evolution. This is where my assumption that a solution exists at all comes in. If time evolution does not respect the constraints (essentially the conditions you point out your initial conditions must satisfy), then a solution will never exist. But if a solution does exist, then clearly its time evolution must satisfy the temporal-derivative relations I described above, which are all uniquely determined, and hence the fields at future times are all uniquely determined.

It is a perfectly good question to ask whether or not the constraints are preserved by time evolution, and there may even be some slick argument showing this in the special case of Maxwell's equations, but unfortunately I don't know of one. What I can say, however, is that the correct way to analyze these constraints would be through the Hamiltonian/Lagrangian formalism. There it can be shown that the constraints are indeed respected by time evolution, but that involves the formalism of constrained Hamiltonian systems which I think is beyond the scope I wanted this answer to have. A nice paper discussing this can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.03616). It has some nice comments on Noether's theorem as a bonus.

Finally, since I mentioned Hamiltonian systems, let me point out that Hamiltonian systems always (at least, I can't think of a loophole off the top of my head) have the property I described above involving isolated time derivatives. This follows immediately from Hamilton's equations:
$$
\dot x=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p},\ \ \ \ \dot p=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}
$$
or the analogous equations for a field system (replace partial derivatives by functional derivatives). These equations always have the temporal derivatives isolated on the left while the right may, at most, depend on spatial derivatives.

Comment: You are right, I missed a to mention the Lorentz Force equation. To keep it simple, we can think that we are dealing only with point like charges, so the Lorentz force is written $$\frac{d\vec P}{dt} = q( \vec E + \vec V \wedge \vec B) $$ with $ \vec P = m\gamma (v) \vec v$ (relativistic notion of momentum). Looking at it, I don't think I can make the first derivative of $\vec x(t)$ (position of one particle) equal to something without time derivatives, so I'm not sure your iteration argument applies.

Comment: When I proved the first theorem I stated, I proved that time evolution preserve the constraints, but on the grounding that the sources were fixed. The evolution in that case were only for the fields. It would be good to show that with the evolution of the sources as well, no sure if that was what you were talking about.

Comment: @TomiU Showing the constraints are preserved regardless takes more machinery than would be reasonable to discuss in a post here, hence the paper I referenced. About the Lorentz force equation: it will be messy and non-covariant, but there's no prohibition to solving for the time derivatives of position (technically 2nd derivatives, I suppose, but this actually doesn't change anything in my answer because you need to specify an initial velocity in addition to initial position). Again, all of this is clearer in a Hamiltonian formulation so everything is manifestly 1st order in time derivatives.